# Add new tab in catalog rule tab in admin magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to add new tab below action tab I searched on the web but unable to get any solution and what should I use ? please give me any idea thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: U want to override Magento module or wanna create new module?

Comment: I want to create new module and then want to add the affected tab thanks!.

Comment: Please refer `vendor\magento\module-cms\view\adminhtml\ui_component\cms_page_form.xml`

Comment: I checked cms module but did not get any idea about my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For adding the new tab in catalog price rule, create the new file name as `catalog_rule_form.xml` under `view/adminhtml/ui_component/` in your custom module.

Add the below content,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="affected_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Affected</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="product_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Product Ids</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">discount_amount</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have just added the sample field. Please do the functionality what you want and don't forget to clear the cache and generation files.